# How to put image in top right corner?

Tags: css, image

How would I fit a small logo like - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNkR.jpg) - in the top right of my border so it fits in and does not resize the border?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
body {
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}
h1 {
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
color: #000;}
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;}
<style>
#logo {
border-style: solid
border-color: #000;
border-width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<h1>example.com</h1>
<p>Examples examples examples.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Qn4c2/ ?

Answer (score -1):

It's really hard to tell what you want to achieve because your code is buggy and you haven't showed how you want to put this image.

One possible solution is for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}
h1 {
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
color: #000;}
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;}

#logo {
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000;
border-width: 100%;
background: url('WdP7OUV.jpg') top right no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<h1>example.com</h1>
<p>Examples examples examples.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

If the image is too big I would strongly recommend you to resize it using any software. However you can also do it the other way adding after:

```
background: url('WdP7OUV.jpg') top right no-repeat;
```

line

```
background-size:80px 80px;
```

But in this case you unnecessary load too big image and it's a waste of transfer so better to scale it in graphic software.